# Launch Play Store top page

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

Is it possible to launch Play Store from another app?
Follwing works fine but i don't need search key words. just want to show top page.
Any idea?

```
public void launchPlayStore(String package) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + package));
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing that method you just simply call your intent with

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store"));
```

Comment: thank you. that works fine. but if "market" is installed instead of Play Store, only browser will be launched. what i want to do is letting user to update from market to Play Store.